# Earth Engine invalid band id when exporting

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to export an image to Assets after adding a band representing time using the following code:

```
//Function to add a timestamp as a new band//
var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start').divide(3.154e10));
};

var img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_062011_20130719');
var img = createTimeBand(img);

Export.image.toAsset({
  image: img,
  scale: 30
});
```

but I am getting this error after a few seconds when I try and run the task:

[image]

There seem to be no problems exporting without the timestamp band, but it is not clear to me why the timestamp causes this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike property names, band names cannot contain the colon character. Try renaming the band you are adding:

```
.metadata('system:time_start').rename('system_time_start')
```