# Earth Engine invalid band id when exporting multiband image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to export a multiband image to my assets using this code:

```
var aoi= ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-1.2, 41.9, 2.8, 43.2]);
// filter 1 Jan to 30 Jan 
var c = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD10A1")
      .filterBounds(aoi)
      .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 30, 'day_of_year')); 

// export collection to multiband image 
var stack = c.toBands().clip(aoi);
Export.image.toAsset(stack, 'stack', 'stack', null, null, null, 500);
```

The Task details window returns the error message: **Error: Invalid band id '2001_01_01_NDSI_Snow_Cover' specified.**

I have tried many things like renaming the bands, changing the data type, etc. without success. [Another post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325867/earth-engine-invalid-band-id-when-exporting) reported a similar issue but I am not using the colon character here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like band names starting with a number is not a valid when exporting images as assets. Before exporting your image, you can rename the bands, prefixing them with a letter:

```
stack.regexpRename('^(.*)', 'b_$1')
```

Comment: Great! It works now. Thank you Daniel.